# Rust lifetime subtyping doesn't work with Cell

Tags: rust, lifetime

Given a value of type `Vec<&'static str>`, I can freely convert that to `Vec<&'r str>`, as `'r` is a subregion of `'static`. That seems to work for most types, e.g. `Vec`, pairs etc. However, it doesn't work for types like `Cell` or `RefCell`. Concretely, `down_vec` compiles, but `down_cell` doesn't:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

fn down_vec<'p, 'r>(x: &'p Vec<&'static str>) -> &'p Vec<&'r str> {
    x
}


fn down_cell<'p, 'r>(x: &'p Cell<&'static str>) -> &'p Cell<&'r str> {
    x
}
```

Giving the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     x
  |     ^ lifetime mismatch
  |
  = note: expected reference `&'p std::cell::Cell<&'r str>`
             found reference `&'p std::cell::Cell<&'static str>`
note: the lifetime `'r` as defined on the function body at 8:18...
 --> src/lib.rs:8:18
  |
8 | fn down_cell<'p, 'r>(x: &'p Cell<&'static str>) -> &'p Cell<&'r str> {
  |                  ^^
  = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```

Why does this not work for `Cell`? How does the compiler track that it doesn't work? Is there an alternative that can make it work?

Comment: That's because `Cell<T>` is invariant in the lifetime of T. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233003/how-does-the-rust-compiler-know-cell-has-internal-mutability/33233793#33233793), specifically the section on "Lifetime Variance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cell` and `RefCell` are different because they allow mutation of the internal value through a shared reference.

To see why this is important, we can write a function that uses `down_cell` to leak a reference to freed memory:

```
fn oops() -> &'static str {
    let cell = Cell::new("this string doesn't matter");
    let local = String::from("this string is local to oops");
    let broken = down_cell(&cell);  // use our broken function to rescope the Cell
    broken.set(&local);             // use the rescoped Cell to mutate `cell`
    cell.into_inner()               // return a reference to `local`
}                                   // uh-oh! `local` is dropped here
```

`oops` contains no `unsafe` blocks, but it compiles, so in order to prevent accessing freed memory the compiler must reject `down_cell`.

The type level explanation for why this is so is because `Cell<T>` and `RefCell<T>` contain an `UnsafeCell<T>`, which makes them *invariant* in `T`, while `Box<T>` and `Vec<T>` are *covariant* in `T`.

The reason `Vec`, `Box` and other container-like structures can be covariant is because those containers require `&mut` access to mutate their contents, and `&mut T` is itself invariant in `T`. You couldn't write a function like `oops` using `down_vec` -- the compiler wouldn't allow it.

### References

- The [Subtyping and Variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) chapter of the Rustonomicon
- [How does the Rust compiler know `Cell` has internal mutability?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33233003/3650362)
- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/3650362)